# HTML/CSS printing page-break with float not working (eg: bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, page-break

**NOTE: Asking and answering it myself because I've spent 3 days trying different methods to find a solution, hoping this helps someone. The question has been asked before but they are old and the answers are unclear or unsatisfactory.**

Trying to add a page-break when printing with elements that have float, eg: using bootstrap grid, doesn't work. The page-break is ignored.

```
<div style="float:right;">floating div</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 break-after">
      Add page break after this element when printing
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      This should be printed on next page
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.break-after {
  page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Firstly, page-break doesn't work inside absolutely positioned elements so make sure your page-break isn't inside one.**

Now, since float is causing the page-break to be ignored, we need to clear the float.

The problem is that `clear: both;` doesn't work if the element with `page-break-after: always;` is a float (eg: `.col-xs-12` in bootstrap).

**The trick is to add 2 new divs with the `clear` and `page-break` after the div you want to add the page-break to:**

```
<div class="page-break-clear"></div>
<div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>

<style type="text/css">
.page-break-clear { 
  clear: both;
}
.page-break {
  page-break-after: always; /* depreciating, use break-after */
  break-after: page;
  height: 0px;
  display: block!important;
}
</style>
```

Putting it together:

```
<div style="float:right;">floating div</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 break-after">
      Add page break after this element when printing
    </div>
    <!-- These 2 new added divs will clear float and add the page break -->
    <div class="page-break-clear"></div>
    <div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      This should be printed on next page
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.page-break-clear { 
  clear: both;
}
.page-break {
  page-break-after: always; /* depreciating, use break-after */
  break-after: page;
  height: 0px;
  display: block!important;
}
</style>
```

as a side-note: I recommend removing the `page-break-after` css for `.break-after` class that was supplied in the question to prevent doubling up on page-breaks incase the floats are removed and it actually works.

Also, to make your life easier if you are using jquery and don't want to manually add those 2 page-break divs, just run the following code which will automatically add them after all elements with the class `.break-after`:

```
$('.break-after').after('<div class="page-break-clear"></div><div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>');
```